# Oracle java 8 unable to find package

Tags: java, linux, docker, dockerfile

This is my dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:jessie

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt install -y locales curl software-properties-common gnupg && \
    echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    echo "deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    echo oracle-java8-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections && \
    apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys EEA14886 && apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl dnsutils oracle-java8-installer ca-certificates && \
    locale-gen en_US.UTF-8 en_us && dpkg-reconfigure locales && dpkg-reconfigure locales && locale-gen C.UTF-8 && /usr/sbin/update-locale LANG=C.UTF-8

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE C.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL C.UTF-8
```

When I try to build the image with this command: `docker build -t javaimage -f java.Dockerfile .`, I get the following error:

```
E: Unable to locate package oracle-java8-installer
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update &&     apt install -y locales curl software-properties-common gnupg &&     echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list &&     echo "deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list &&     echo oracle-java8-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections &&     apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys EEA14886 && apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl dnsutils oracle-java8-installer ca-certificates &&     locale-gen en_US.UTF-8 en_us && dpkg-reconfigure locales && dpkg-reconfigure locales && locale-gen C.UTF-8 && /usr/sbin/update-locale LANG=C.UTF-8' returned a non-zero code: 100
roger@NB-SBDEV1149:~/Projet
```

Does anyone know how do I solve this? Using openjdk is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Oracles new License for Java, that PPA is no longer valid. 
Check here: https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java

> The new Oracle Technology Network License Agreement for Oracle Java SE
>   is substantially different from prior Oracle JDK licenses. The new
>   license permits certain uses, such as personal use and development
>   use, at no cost -- but other uses authorized under prior Oracle JDK
>   licenses may no longer be available. Please review the terms carefully
>   before downloading and using this product. An FAQ is available here:
>   https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/oracle-jdk-faqs.html
>
> Oracle Java downloads now require logging in to an Oracle account to
>   download Java updates, like the latest Oracle Java 8u211 / Java SE
>   8u212. Because of this I cannot update the PPA with the latest Java
>   (and the old links were broken by Oracle).
>
> For this reason, THIS PPA IS DISCONTINUED (unless I find some way
>   around this limitation).

If you want, you can use `openjdk` by doing `apt-get install openjdk-8-jre` instead